# C++ invoke nested template class destructor

Tags: c++, templates, destructor, nested-class

Suppose I have a variable x of type std::vector::iterator that was allocated (for other reasons) with placement new, e.g.

```
new((void*)&x) std::vector<int>::iterator();
```

How does one call its destructor in a standards compliant way? Doing

```
x.std::vector<int>::iterator::~iterator();
```

for example works in gcc but not clang.

Comment: Consider x to be a member of a C struct, e.g. `struct A { std::vector<int>::iterator x; ... }` and you're given a `struct A*` to initialize and destroy.  (In my case, it's a Python extension class instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All standard (and standard-compliant) iterators follow the [`Iterator` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator), which is required to be [`Destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Destructible). Thus, it suffice to simply call the iterator's destructor just as you would in any other (non-trivial) types constructed with placement new.

```
x.~iterator_type();   // where x is an iterator
```

Note that if you refer to the iterator through a pointer, you must use the `->` operator:

```
#include <vector>


int main() {
    auto buffer = new char[sizeof(std::vector<int>::iterator)];

    auto iterator = new((void*)buffer) std::vector<int>::iterator();
    iterator->std::vector<int>::iterator::~iterator();

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

[**LIVE EXAMPLE (GCC)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1731290bd7828530)

**UPDATE:** It seems that Clang has some problems compiling the (I presume standards-compliant) code. You can make a work-around on this by providing an indirection when calling the destructor:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void call_destructor(T* x) {
    x->~T();
}

int main() {
    auto buffer = new char[sizeof(std::vector<int>::iterator)];

    auto iterator = new((void*)buffer) std::vector<int>::iterator();
    //iterator->std::vector<int>::iterator::~iterator();
    call_destructor(iterator);

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

[**LIVE EXAMPLE (clang)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9b5806c14df9055)

**UPDATE:** Yah. It's a bug in clang: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12350. [See Dieter Lücking's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847816/c-invoke-nested-template-class-destructor/21848011?noredirect=1#comment33073778_21848011).

---

<sup>I'm very sorry to all of you, especially to the OP, for [this mess](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21848011/revisions).</sup>

Comment: It is no destructor declaration, but a destructor call. (Your answer was better before). It's actually clang bug: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12350

Comment: @DieterLücking You're right. Please don't be like me.

Comment: Or perhaps it's not a bug but clang detecting a C++ error no other compiler can see? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623303